# Grails .save() not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When i am writing the .save() in grails it is inserting a new row in the db table. However, not persisting data in the object.
I have tried with .save(flush: true) but had no luck.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What version of grails?  And, have you tried .validate() and .hasErrors() to make sure that all of your data is valid?

Comment: Version is 2.5.1. Yes i have tried with .valiadte() and .hasErrors().

Comment: If you think you can rule out a validation error you fail to catch, please also provide the code to back this up.

Comment: What do u mean by inserting row but not persisting data

Answer (score 5):

Try `save(failOnError:true)` or check the return value of `save()` -- which is *success/failure* in Groovy-truth.

You can also add `logSql: true` to your application.yml datasource and

```
logger 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder', TRACE, ['STDOUT']
logger 'org.hibernate.SQL', TRACE, ['STDOUT']
```

to your logback.groovy

Comment: @AbhisekPattnaik whas does "does not work mean"?  Do you get an exception?  Well, bingo, that is the reasons why it does not save.

Comment: I am currently experiencing this, inside a loop, using `withTransaction`. I even get an ID, which keeps incrementing. Meaning, to me, the database is recieving the transaction, but just not commiting it... I get no errors, tried flush:true, and simply have no actually saved records.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the object you want to save is not validated. Means that not match with the minimum constraints described on the domain class.

Debug your code and run the validated method, after that take a look on the errors property.

```
object.validate()
object.errors
```

Take a look
https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Remember that all not declared attributes on the constraints closure, are compulsory by default for saving the object